Problems installing adwaita-qt -dark mode option for VLC in Ubuntu 24.10
When I attempt to install GNOME Adwaita dark mode the following results appear.
goose@goose-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:~$ sudo apt install adwaita-qt
[sudo] password for goose: 
E: Malformed entry 1 in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources (URI parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.

BTW I have tried several versions of VLC and all fail to read the adwaita in the preferences menu on VLC.
Has anybody encountered this problem before?

The file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources mentioned in your error message has an error that needs to be corrected; the error is found on line 1 (also mentioned in the message).  You need to correct that line, OR for us to help, we need to know what's inside it, as your details currently only show the line number & file containing error(s).   Note:  subsequent lines may contain errors too, as handling of file aborts on first error

This question is similar to: How do I remove a malformed line from my ubuntu.sources?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guiverc ..thanks for your reply..I'm very new to ubuntu can you please tell me how to get inside /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources file so I can post the results..thanks

is this it     /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-vlc-noble.sources
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntuhandbook1-ubuntu-vlc-noble.sources.save

You can view the contents using the command cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources  ie. the cat command same as unix with the file given as operand and what to view. To edit on my 24.10 I could use sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources though I prefer other editors myself so I'd use a different command..  Terminal commands on Ubuntu are general POSIX (newer name for a 'standard' unix; cat introduced in 1976 to unix v1)

Thanks https://askubuntu.com/users/469152/guivercg
goose@goose-HP-EliteBook-840-G2:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources
Types: deb
URIs: cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS Jammy Jellyfish - Release amd64 (20240911)]/
Suites: jammy
Components: main restricted

i then ran sudo nano and ......                             ypes: deb
URIs: cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS Jammy Jellyfish - Release amd64 (20240911)]/
Suites: jammy
Components: main restricted
^G Help      ^O Write Out ^W Where Is  ^K Cut       ^T Execute   ^C Location
^X Exit      ^R Read File ^\ Replace   ^U Paste     ^J Justify   ^/ Go To Line
not sure what to do next?

So I'll throw in my two-cents. Was this an upgrade from 24.04 or a fresh install ? Have you checked your Software & Updates app under Other Software ?
That is where most all PPA's will be found. Follow that PPA to the website so you can update the repository. You may need to delete the PPA in question before adding the "new" repo. (BTW - Make sure that the Canonical Partners box is checked. ) For accessing the file itself, I use root in my file manager to modify files. So with Nautilus, go to /etc/apt/ --and open-- /sources.list.d/ as ROOT. Now you can delete or modify the offending file. (You may need to install nautilus-admin with sudo apt-get install nautilus-admin ...) Nautilus-admin enables root access to folder and files through file manager.
NOTE: I always use Synaptic Package Manager to manage all software. It's the first thing I do after an install: sudo apt-get install synaptic --- I highly recommend installing it.
